# Why do we need a "lengthy proof" to show $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have been reviewing my intro to analysis course and stumbled on a rather easy proof. The proof is standard, suppose $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above and reach a contradiction using the Completeness Axiom. My question is why do we even need to do that? Consider the following proof:

To show $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above is the same as showing that given  $n_1\in\mathbb{N}$, there exits $n_2$ s.t. $n_2>n_1$ and $n_2\in\mathbb{N}$. Letting $n_2=n_1+1$ completes the proof. Why do we even need to use the completeness axiom if we already know $\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105515/archimedean-property-of-real-numbers

Comment: yes I think it is ridiculous too : proving that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above is important only when you are an [automatic theorem prover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving) not a human. and I guess it is suppose to teach you how to prove things from the axioms (and the inference rules ! ) as if you didn't know what they were representing.

Comment: The assertion is intuitively reasonable, there is no real number that is greater than every integer. However, there are important "reals-like" structures in which $\mathbb{N}$ is indeed bounded above.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded from above in the set of countable ordinals and your proof still holds in  that case so there is something wrong with your proof.

Comment: @user1952009, I don't think its ridiculous. How do you know that that the only model of the complete ordered field axioms is $\mathbb{R}$? Maybe it has other, non-isomorphic models. To check that this isn't the case, you need to prove that every complete ordered field is Archimedean.

Comment: @goblin : in my opinion you are using complicated words for talking of the usual metric completion of $\mathbb{Q}$. those complicated words are not interesting in every contexts. and in real-analysis course (1st or 2nd year of maths), those complicated words totally lack of context. no ?

Comment: @user1952009, if I were trying to communicate with the OP, I'd be using more more-familiar (but also more long-winded) words and phrases. I'm using those "big complicated words" to talk to you, not the OP. In any event, my point remains, which is that to check that the relevant axioms pin down our intuitions about $\mathbb{R}$, you have to prove these sorts of things. What's so ridiculous about that?

Comment: @goblin : sorry, I didn't mean you were not right

Comment: @user1952009, okay. Well I agree with the sentiment that sometimes technical jargon is overused when simpler but more long-winded phrases would suffice.

Comment: @goblin : and if I want to allow convergence to $\pm \infty$, similar as the convergence to any real number, what will it destroy in the real numbers field ?

Comment: @user1952009, if I've understood your question correctly, you're basically saying: what makes $[-\infty,\infty]$ fail to be a complete ordered field? I guess the main problem is the loss of associativity for addition: $$(-\infty+\infty)+1 = 0+1 = 1, \qquad -\infty+(\infty+1) = -\infty+\infty = 0$$

Comment: @goblin : hence we are not in a field anymore. and it corresponds to the intuition that $\infty-\infty$ can be anything. but in $\mathbb{C}$ it seems we need the Riemann sphere, which works fine for the convergence to $\infty$, but it becomes a point, not a set of isolated points (or a circle), and hence $+ \infty = -\infty$, we can do the same in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Sure, we can try to make $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ into an ordered field. But that doesn't work, either: we end up having to choose $\infty$ as its own additive inverse, so $\infty+\infty=0$, but this means: $$(\infty+\infty) + 1 = 0+1 = 1, \qquad \infty +(\infty+1) = \infty+\infty = 0$$ Again, no associativity.

Comment: I think you missed the whole point of "bounded above". To show that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above you must show that if $K$ is any real number then there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K < n$. What you are trying to do is to find a natural number greater than a given natural number. This has nothing to do with "bounded above", rather it has something to do with the infinite cardinality of set $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 12):

Saying that $\Bbb N$ is not bounded above in $\Bbb R$ is not the same as saying that for all $x\in \Bbb N$ there exists $y\in \Bbb N$ such that $y>x$. In fact, there are several subsets of $\Bbb R$ which satisfy this property and are bounded above, namely the interval $[0,1)$, which has $1$ as an upper bound. What you must prove is that for all $x\in\Bbb R$ there exists $y\in \Bbb N$ such that $y>x$, which is different.

Comment: I didn't realize the distinction between $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above in itself. The latter will be trivial, right?

Comment: @Kun The latter is trivial and your proof is valid, but they are not the same. For example, $(0, 1)$ is not bounded above in itself. Try to find a biggest element of $(0, 1)$. Can you do it? Are you sure? (If you find a biggest element, tell me and I will find a bigger one.) Even though $(0, 1)$ has no biggest element, $1$ is still a upper bound of the set.

Comment: @Kun Per se, the fact that the ordering of $\Bbb N$ has no maximum should follow easily by its set-theoretic definition. If i recall correctly my last ZFC exam, proving the good definition of the ordering of $\Bbb N$ from scratch was a bit tedious.

Comment: Wait...Assuming $0 \notin \Bbb{N}$, can't you just define $<$ as $\{(a, b) \in \Bbb{N}^2 \mid (\exists c \in \Bbb{N})(a+c=b)\}$ and then prove the relation is irreflexive, transitive, and asymmetric? That seems pretty easy. Then, to prove it has no maximum, you just prove the Well-Ordering Theorem and go from there.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Perhaps, but then you need to have already proven some things on the sum, namely the fact that $$a+c=a\implies c=0$$ Discussing it here in detail would be long, I fear.

Comment: OK. I will ask about it in another question on another day.

Comment: Which book should I consult to get a more elaborate discussion of constructing the number systems, namely $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ from scratch?

Comment: @Kun Introductory books of Set Theory usually go through the whole ordeal of defining $\Bbb N$ and constructing $\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ from it. For instance, Hrbacek, Jech, *Introduction to set theory* does it in chapters 4 and 7 (third edition).

Answer (score 8):

Maybe a picture will help. $\;\!\;\!$

[image]

So the purpose of the "lengthy proof" is to show that complete ordered fields are never too lengthy. Now that's irony!

Answer (score 0):

Your proof shows that there is no biggest element of $\Bbb{N}$. However, just because there is no biggest element of $\Bbb{N}$ does not mean there is no upper bound.

Take $(0, 1)$, for example. If you have some biggest element $m \in (0, 1)$, then we know $m < 1$, so $1-m > 0$ and thus $m+\frac{1-m}{2}=\frac{1+m}{2} > m$. Clearly, since $m < 1$, $1+m < 2$, so $\frac{1+m}{2} < 1$, meaing $\frac{1+m}{2} \in (0, 1)$. Thus, we have found a bigger element than the biggest element of $(0, 1)$, so there is no biggest element of $(0, 1)$.

However, we can not deduce from the fact that $(0, 1)$ has no biggest element that it is not bounded above. Clearly, $1 \in \Bbb{R}$ is an upper bound of $(0, 1)$ even though $(0, 1)$ has no biggest element.

Thus, even though it seems obvious that $\Bbb{N}$ has no upper bound, we need to use the Completeness Axiom in order to prove it because that tells us about the real numbers themselves. In fact, **there are some models of the real numbers like [the hyperreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number#The_transfer_principle) where $\Bbb{N}$ is actually bounded above because the Completeness Axiom does not hold**. However, your proof that $\Bbb{N}$ has no biggest element would still hold in the hyperreals, but that doesn't mean it has no upper bound.